# Lazy loading in Preact routes not working

Tags: reactjs, frontend, lazy-loading, preact

I'm trying to use lazy loading in preact and this is my code (`routes/form-page.js`):

```
import {lazy, Suspense} from 'preact/compat';
.
.
.
const Form = lazy(() => import("../components/form"));

const FormPage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (

        <Grid container justifyContent="center" className={classes.root}>
            <Suspense fallback={<Grid item xs={10} className={classes.suspense}>Loading ...</Grid>}>
               <Form/>
            </Suspense>
        </Grid>
    )
};
```

it's ok in development but in building (running `preact build`), it returns error:

`ERROR Template execution failed: [object Promise]`

what is wrong?

Comment: What build tool are you using? How are you lazily importing `Form`?

Comment: Are you using Preact-CLI? If so, I don't believe suspense is supported. There are other ways to code split though, so I'll write an answer showing how.

Answer (score 0):

With Preact-CLI, suspense is not supported when prerendering. See [preact-cli#1359](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues/1359). You can disable prerendering with `preact build --no-prerender`.

There are other methods of code splitting outlined in the project [ReadMe](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli#features), such as using certain directories or by using the `async!` prefix in your imports.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is currently an **experimental feature** and it is a bug in preact.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with Preact. The build tool, Preact-CLI, does not support suspense when prerendering. It's a known limitation and there's an existing issue open for it, see [preact-cli#1359](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues/1359).